# Ruby API call to get data from complex json

Tags: json, ruby, rest

I'm making an API GET call using Ruby - the call is made to a Learning Management System and returns the following JSON:

```
{
    "id": 12345,
    "body": null,
    "url": null,
    "grade": "75",
    "score": 75,
    "submitted_at": "2020-05-02T11:30:53Z",
    "assignment_id": 9876,
    "user_id": 1111,
    "submission_type": "online_upload",
    "workflow_state": "graded",
    "grade_matches_current_submission": true,
    "graded_at": "2017-06-05T08:47:49Z",
    "grader_id": 2222,
    "attempt": 1,
    "cached_due_date": "2020-05-03T15:00:00Z",
    "excused": false,
    "late_policy_status": null,
    "points_deducted": null,
    "grading_period_id": null,
    "late": false,
    "missing": false,
    "seconds_late": 0,
    "entered_grade": "75",
    "entered_score": 75,
    "preview_url": "https://etcetc",
    "turnitin_data": {
        "attachment_33333": {
            "status": "scored",
            "object_id": "44444444",
            "similarity_score": 0,
            "web_overlap": 0,
            "publication_overlap": 0,
            "student_overlap": 0,
            "state": "none"
        }
    },
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": 33333,
            "uuid": "kjsdkjhsdfkhsfd",
            "folder_id": 55555,
            "display_name": "Submission.pdf",
            "filename": "Submission.pdf",
            "content-type": "application/pdf",
            "url": "https://etcetc",
            "size": 2668226,
            "created_at": "2020-05-02T11:30:51Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-06-06T15:01:46Z",
            "unlock_at": null,
            "locked": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "lock_at": null,
            "hidden_for_user": false,
            "thumbnail_url": null,
            "modified_at": "2020-05-02T11:30:51Z",
            "mime_class": "pdf",
            "media_entry_id": null,
            "locked_for_user": false,
            "preview_url": "api/etcetc"
        }
    ],
    "submission_comments": [
        {
            "id": 99999,
            "comment": "here’s a comment",
            "author_id": 1,
            "author_name": "Mickey Mouse",
            "created_at": "2020-05-15T12:54:08Z",
            "edited_at": null,
            "avatar_path": "/images/users/1",
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "display_name": " Mickey Mouse ",
                "avatar_image_url": "https://etcetc",
                "html_url": "https://etcetc"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 223344,
            "comment": "another comment",
            "author_id": 2,
            "author_name": "Donald Duck",
            "created_at": "2020-06-05T10:48:51Z",
            "edited_at": null,
            "avatar_path": "/images/users/2",
            "author": {
                "id": 2,
                "display_name": "Donald Duck",
                "avatar_image_url": "https://etcetc",
                "html_url": "https://etcetc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to be able to retrieve specific values from "submission_comments", namely the values for "comment", "author_id" and "author_name". At the moment the best I can do is retrieve "submission_comments" as one big entity. Here's how I'm getting that far:

```
require 'typhoeus'
require 'link_header'
require 'json'
require 'csv'

the_url = 'https://etctetc' 
token = 'mytoken'
api_endpoint = '/api/etc'
output_csv = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Ruby Canvas course\assignment_comments.csv'

CSV.open(output_csv, 'wb') do |csv|
    csv << ["user_id", "TII", "marker"]
end

request_url = "#{the_url}#{api_endpoint}"
count = 0
more_data = true
while more_data  
    get_comments = Typhoeus::Request.new(
        request_url,    
        method: :get,
        headers: { authorization: "Bearer #{token}" }
        )

        get_comments.on_complete do |response|
        #get next link
            links = LinkHeader.parse(response.headers['link']).links
            next_link = links.find { |link| link['rel'] == 'next' } 
            request_url = next_link.href if next_link 
            if next_link && "#{response.body}" != "[]"
                more_data = true
            else
                more_data = false
            end

        if response.code == 200
            data = JSON.parse(response.body)
            data.each do |comments|
                CSV.open(output_csv, 'a') do |csv|
                    csv << [comments['id'], comments['turnitin_data'], comments['submission_comments']]
                end
            end
        else
            puts "Something went wrong! Response code was #{response.code}"
        end
    end

    get_comments.run
end
puts "Script done running"
```

I'm new to this (the ruby code is based on an exercise so I may not fully understand it)- any help/advice would be really appreciated!

EDIT: I should also note that this isn't the total JSON response I'm dealing with - this is just one of ten items that are returned

Comment: Just like to add an apology that I did try to get the JSON to present in it's 'pretty' form above but that doesn't seem to have worked :(

Comment: The only thing you were missing is indenting each line with 4 spaces (select the block and press cmd+k). FTFY.

Comment: So your question is about how to retrieve a value from JSON in ruby? Maybe you can remove the API call sauce, which seems to be unnecessary for your topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
"submission_comments": [
        {
            "id": 99999,
        }
]
```

the `[]` means it is array. `{}` means it is an object.

So you probably need to do something like this:

```
json["submission_comments"].first["id"]
```

or better iterate through it:

```
ids = json["submission_comments"].map{|comment| comment["id"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get the variables you need if you can read the JSON file in as text, then use Ruby's JSON.parse(...) method on it. I think the main problem is that JSON uses `null` but Ruby hashes use `nil`. You could do a string replace or try something like this (I did not modify your JSON, only put it into a single quoted string):

```
json_text = '{
    "id": 12345,
    "body": null,
    "url": null,
    "grade": "75",
    "score": 75,
    "submitted_at": "2020-05-02T11:30:53Z",
    "assignment_id": 9876,
    "user_id": 1111,
    "submission_type": "online_upload",
    "workflow_state": "graded",
    "grade_matches_current_submission": true,
    "graded_at": "2017-06-05T08:47:49Z",
    "grader_id": 2222,
    "attempt": 1,
    "cached_due_date": "2020-05-03T15:00:00Z",
    "excused": false,
    "late_policy_status": null,
    "points_deducted": null,
    "grading_period_id": null,
    "late": false,
    "missing": false,
    "seconds_late": 0,
    "entered_grade": "75",
    "entered_score": 75,
    "preview_url": "https://etcetc",
    "turnitin_data": {
        "attachment_33333": {
            "status": "scored",
            "object_id": "44444444",
            "similarity_score": 0,
            "web_overlap": 0,
            "publication_overlap": 0,
            "student_overlap": 0,
            "state": "none"
        }
    },
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": 33333,
            "uuid": "kjsdkjhsdfkhsfd",
            "folder_id": 55555,
            "display_name": "Submission.pdf",
            "filename": "Submission.pdf",
            "content-type": "application/pdf",
            "url": "https://etcetc",
            "size": 2668226,
            "created_at": "2020-05-02T11:30:51Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-06-06T15:01:46Z",
            "unlock_at": null,
            "locked": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "lock_at": null,
            "hidden_for_user": false,
            "thumbnail_url": null,
            "modified_at": "2020-05-02T11:30:51Z",
            "mime_class": "pdf",
            "media_entry_id": null,
            "locked_for_user": false,
            "preview_url": "api/etcetc"
        }
    ],
    "submission_comments": [
        {
            "id": 99999,
            "comment": "here’s a comment",
            "author_id": 1,
            "author_name": "Mickey Mouse",
            "created_at": "2020-05-15T12:54:08Z",
            "edited_at": null,
            "avatar_path": "/images/users/1",
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "display_name": " Mickey Mouse ",
                "avatar_image_url": "https://etcetc",
                "html_url": "https://etcetc"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 223344,
            "comment": "another comment",
            "author_id": 2,
            "author_name": "Donald Duck",
            "created_at": "2020-06-05T10:48:51Z",
            "edited_at": null,
            "avatar_path": "/images/users/2",
            "author": {
                "id": 2,
                "display_name": "Donald Duck",
                "avatar_image_url": "https://etcetc",
                "html_url": "https://etcetc"
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

Part I added:

```
  ruby_hash = JSON.parse(json_text)
  submission_comments = ruby_hash["submission_comments"]
  submission_comments.each do |submission_comment|
    comment = submission_comment["comment"]
    author_id = submission_comment["author_id"]
    author_name = submission_comment["author_name"]
    puts "Comment: #{comment}, Author ID: #{author_id}, Author Name: #{author_name}\n\n"
  end
```

Terminal Result:

> => Comment: here’s a comment, Author ID: 1, Author Name: Mickey Mouse
>
> => Comment: another comment, Author ID: 2, Author Name: Donald Duck

---

Edit: I added a jenky af one-liner version just for fun (presuming the `json_text` variable above is already initialized)

```
JSON.parse(json_text)["submission_comments"]
    .map{|txt| puts(["comment","author_id","author_name"]
        .map{|k| k.instance_eval{"#{upcase}: #{txt[to_s]}"}}.join(', '))}
```

> COMMENT: here’s a comment, AUTHOR_ID: 1, AUTHOR_NAME: Mickey Mouse
>
> COMMENT: another comment, AUTHOR_ID: 2, AUTHOR_NAME: Donald Duck

Comment: Hi oMiKeY, thanks for this - I can get both versions to run if I manually add the single quotes at the beginning/end as you have. I'll need to let the script handle adding those though, and I'm failing at that with this attempt: json2 = "'#{json_text}'"
puts json2

Comment: i think that really should work... but theres always: `json2 = "'" + json_text + "'"` (if I understand your situation correctly)